# Shiny withProgress: detect if close icon has been clicked

Tags: r, shiny, progress-bar

I want to display the progress of my long-running function in shiny. I use `message` in the long-running function to emit progress messages and `withCallingHandlers` in the shiny server function to update the progress bar.

```
long_run_op <- function(num_iter, verbose=TRUE) {
    for (x in 1:num_iter) {
        if(verbose) message("working... [value=",x,"]")
        Sys.sleep(0.5)
    }
    if(verbose) message("calculation finished.")
    return(rnorm(num_iter))
}

library(shinydashboardPlus)
    
ui <- shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
    header=shinydashboardPlus::dashboardHeader(),
    sidebar = shinydashboardPlus::dashboardSidebar(),

    body=shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
        shinydashboardPlus::box(
            status="primary", width=12,
            shiny::fluidRow(
                shiny::column(6,
                    shiny::numericInput('num_iter', 'Iterations', 10, min=2, max=20)
                ),
                shiny::column(6,
                    shiny::actionButton("run", "Run")
                )
            )
        ),
        
        shinydashboardPlus::box(
            status="primary", width=12,
            shiny::plotOutput("result")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    shiny::observeEvent(input$run, {
        shiny::withProgress(
            withCallingHandlers(
                out <- long_run_op(
                    num_iter=input$num_iter,
                    verbose=TRUE
                ),
                message=function(m) if(grepl("\\[value=[0-9]+\\]", m$message)) {
                    val <- as.numeric(gsub(".*\\[value=([0-9]+)\\].*$", "\\1", m$message))
                    cat("Stacksize: ", session$progressStack$size(),"\n")
                    shiny::setProgress(value=val)
                }
            ),
            message="working...",
            max=input$num_iter,
            value=0
        )
        output$result <- shiny::renderPlot(plot(out))
    })
}

app <- shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
shiny::runApp(app, launch.browser=TRUE)
```

This works fine. Now the progress bar notification pop-up has a close button. If I press this button, the progress bar pop-up disappears, but the calculation continues, leaving the shiny UI unresponsive. This is very undesirable.

Is there a way to either disable (i.e. to not display) the close icon in the progress bar notification or to figure out if the close icon has been clicked?

**What I tried so far**: I inspected `shiny::setProgress` and learned about `session$progressStack$size()`. However, this value is `1` even if I press the close icon.

I also learned about `session$progressStack$peek()`, which returns a `R6` object with a private field `closed`. But since it is private, I cannot access that information, can I? I tried `x$private$closed` and `x$closed`, which both return `NULL`. Anyway, the value of the `closed` field seems to be `FALSE` whether I clicked the close icon or not.

EDIT1: It seems that setting `style="old"` in `withProgress` does not display a close icon. That will be fine for me now. It would be nice to give the user the possibility to cancel the long-run operation, but Javascript knowledge is very limited. I tried

```
shinyjs::runjs("
    $().on('click', '.shiny-notification-close', function() {
        Shiny.setInputValue('pb_close_click', 'TRUE');
    });"
)
```

before calling `long_run_op`, but I cannot find the `pb_close_click` value in R. I also tried

```
pb_close_click <- FALSE
shinyjs::onclick('.shiny-notification-close',
    pb_close_click <- TRUE
)
```

but the `pb_close_click` variable is not altered if the close icon is clicked. Any hint appreciated.

Comment: I don't have any straight up answer, but you could maybe inspect the progress bar element, and see what id or class the 'x' button has, and then make a javascript event listener that fires a Shiny.setInputValue, when that selector/id/class is pressed.  Then have a shiny reactive that depends on this input, that will shut down the process. Just an idea

Comment: the x icon seems to have class `.shiny-notification-close`. Will try that out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set in the css in the UI:
tags$style(".shiny-notification-close {display: none}")